# How to set the dropdownlist value in angularjs.

Tags: angularjs

I tried below code to set the dropdownlist value to some integer value.

My code is as below:

```
 <select class='form-control input-new' id="ConditionTypeSelect" data-msg-required="" name="conditionTypeName" data-ng-model="listingProfile.conditionTypeId" data-ng-options="ct.conditionTypeId as ct.conditionType for ct in amazonCategoryConditionType">
                                                <option value=""></option>
                                            </select>
```

`data-ng-model="listingProfile.conditionTypeId" contains integer values.`

Can you please let me know how this can be achieved ?

Comment: what did u get with this code ?

Comment: I did not got any exception with this code. I wanted to set the dropdown value to the value comming in listingProfile.conditionTypeId but that too didn't happen.

Comment: use the below answer @Vishal

Answer (score 0):

The value for ng-model should be the currently selected value.

```
<select data-ng-model="currentvalue" data-ng-options="x.value as x.name for x in listofvalues">
 </select>
```

For this code, define $scope.currentvalue to be a singular object and $scope.listofvalues to be the list of objects to choose from. Setting $scope.currentvalue to the value or the index will not work!

For this code, the object should have an attribute value and an attribute name.

Comment: Hi popovitsj, actually the value comming in data-ng-model="listingProfile.conditionTypeId" is "9" i hope this is right and in code section 'data-ng-options="ct.conditionTypeId as ct.conditionType for ct in amazonCategoryConditionType"',  amazonCategoryConditionType is a List of object which is comming from database but the dropdown is not set to value "9".

Comment: The ng-model variable should point to an object in the list, not to the value of it.